# laravel DB::raw() weird behaviour

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have this query:

```
$feed = Feed::where(DB::raw('LOWER(feeds.title) LIKE LOWER("%'.$a.'%")'))->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->paginate(10);
```

But for some reason Laravel changes it to:

```
SQL: select * from `feeds` where LOWER(feeds.title) LIKE LOWER("%variable%") is null order by `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0
```

Notice the `is null` after the WHERE clause. Why is it changing it like this and how am I supposed to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `whereRaw` and just pass it a string.

You're not supposed to use `where()` like that. It takes 3 parameters, like so:

```
where('column', 'operator', 'value');
```

If you leave the out the 3rd parameter it will default to a `whereNull()`, which is why you're getting **"is null**" appended. To put a raw statement in a where clause you should use `whereRaw().`